# Bashrc file and short circuiting file comment with a message with prompt. how?

Tags: bash

I am a complete newb with bashrc and I want to shortcircuit a command in the termal.. display a message with a "y/n" prompt. If I type "y", then the original command I did goes thru.

I don't think this is hard, I just need a push in the proper direction. I did some searching and nothing seemed to even hint at anything like this.

for example:

I type:

```
cvs -m commit /some/file/structure
```

because I put: "cvs -m commit"

bash intercedes, and displays message:

```
"Please make sure you......"
continue with command "y/n":
```

something along those lines. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: If you just need a push, I might suggest using a custom command through ```aias```, although maybe in bash_profile instead of .bash.rc

Answer (score 0):

.bashrc only gets executed when starting the shell, not for every command, I don't know how it could help. If there's a certain command that you wish to add confirmation to, you could build an alias or a little script with the same name as the original command, and make sure it's in the PATH before the real command. The script can read its arguments and pass them to the original command after displaying the y/n prompt.